# mvnrnd function using matlab error message?

Tags: matlab, simulation

I'm creating a gibbs sampling algorithm and the following message appears when I've used mvnrnd function:

`??? Error using ==> mvnrnd
SIGMA must be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.`

note I've used chol function before using mvnrnd

```
nu02=chol(nu01);
nu0=s*nu02;
z = mvnrnd(mu0,nu0)';
```

what can i do to solve the problem?

Comment: achieve to build a positive semi-definite 'nu01'? Cholesky will not work if the matrix is not positive semi-definite

Comment: is there any way to force the matrix to be positive semi definit??

Comment: Without knowing more about your program we can't really offer any help other than comply with the error message.

Comment: Also the thing is not if you can transform nu0 to be positive semi-def, but nu0 to be created positibe semi-definite with the correct mathemathical equations. Is not that Matlab needs nu0 to be like that but the Mathemathics need nu0 to be like that.

Comment: There could be two reasons for the error: either `nu0` is not square, and/or it is not >0. Since `chol` produces an upper triangular matrix, your matrix `s` must be such that all elements of product `s*nu02` are non-zero. Have you tried inspecting the values of `nu0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your expecting that `nu0` should be symmetric positive semi-definite at the time you pass it in to `mvnrnd`, but for some reason there are very small numerical issues that make it not quite symmetric.

There might be another issue, but if this is the problem, you can force it to be exactly symmetric with the command

```
nu0 = (nu0 + nu0')/2;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You may want to check whether the difference is in fact small by using: max(max(abs((nu0 + nu0')))); If this is a small number i guess it should be ok.